# Python- How to find the average of multiple values/key in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, average

I have a dictionary that looks like this. . .

```
CombinedDict = {'Abamectin': [63, 31, 53], 'Difenzoquat metilsulfate': [185, 49, 152], 'Chlorpyrifos': [14, 26, 56], 'Dibutyl phthalate': [25, -17, -18]
```

and so forth. In total I have 48 different keys.

What I am trying to get is the average of the three numbers. So I would get a dict that looks like this . . .

```
  AvgDictName = {'Abamectin': [49], 'Difenzoquat metilsulfate': [128], 'Chlorpyrifos': [32], 'Dibutyl phthalate': [-3] . . .
```

I have tried using this line

```
    AvgDictName = dict([(key, float(sum([int(i) for i in values])) / len(values)) for key, values in CombinedDict])
```

But I am getting *too many values to unpack error*
Any ideas? I think it could also be done by making the dict into a list and finding the average from a list using len and sum commands and then converting back to a dict but I do not really know how to go about that. Thank you, I have a feeling this should easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to iterate over [`CombinedDict.items()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) or [`CombinedDict.iteritems()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) if you want to unpack into `key, values`

Comment: `.iteritems()` for python 2.x

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, `.items()` is actually better in the sense that it's "Python 3 proof", unless you really need to optimize for large value lists.

Comment: @BenHoyt: That's what the 2to3 tool is for. Should I wrap all my print statements in parentheses as well?

Comment: @Eric: If you use `from __future__ import print_function` :P (sorry, you just picked a wrong example)

Answer (score 0):

`for x in dictionary: ...` iterates over the keys of a dictionary.

Unless the keys themselves are tuples, `for a, b in dictionary` will error since it attempts to unpack the key into two values.

For iterating dictionaries, you should use [`items()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), [`keys()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys), and [`values()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) (or their `iter*` equivalents in python 2.x)

Answer (score 0):

```
    python 3.2

    >>> [(i,sum(v)//len(v)) for i,v in t.items()]
```